# How to use usb barcode scanner with python?

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, barcode-scanner, raw-input

I am trying to take input from usb barcode scanner in python (Raspberry pi).
Barcode scanner works as keyboard so i need to press enter key after scanning .I dont want to press enterkey after scanning the data, the data
(barcode) should be directly stored in to variable. How to do it?

Comment: So make the scanner to send the data without Enter key.

Comment: Barcode canner doesnt act like serial device,it is detected as keyboard ,so @Psytho how to make the scanner send the data without enter key? and store the barcode in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last the problem is solved, in barcode scanner there is a mode where automatic enter key pressing is done.Just have to scan the enterkey barcode from the barcoe scanner manual.